# all android studio emulators' screen are upside down

Tags: android-studio

Every emulator i create appears the same and sometimes when i click in position, it clicks somewhere else.
i am using latest version of android studio android-studio-2023.1.1.28
and tried on pixel 3a apI 34 (android 14.0) and Pixel 7 API 33 (Android 13.0)

i tried to upload screenshot here but it failed, so i upload it to drive and here is the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7lBrKgjKrcMgd2skQcCQeg92fs4TffL/view?usp=sharing

i reinstalled android studio
delete all emulators and install them again
the issue still there

Comment: Please don't use external services for hosting screenshots. Stackexchange contains an image uploading feature.